# Angular basic guard

Tags: angular

There is possible to create guard with roles args?

I want something like this:

```
  {
    path: 'app1',
    loadChildren: 'src/app/app1/app1.module#App1Module',
    canActivate: [new Guard ([Role.Admin, Role.app1])]
  }
```

and the activate function:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    const user = this.authenticationService.user;
    if (user &&
        user.roles &&
        user.roles.some((role) => this.roles.includes(role))) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: what s purpose of passing role , that role you can access via your authenticationservice right ?, if you just want allow admin to access path then you can put that condition in your canactivate method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the default Guard of Angular, But yes there is one awesome package is there for the same -

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-permissions

Which allows you to guard your router as well as some portion of templates too, and it is very easy to use for example -

```
{ path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate: [NgxPermissionsGuard],
    data: {
      permissions: {
        only: 'ADMIN','SuperAdmin'
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: i didn't know about data options, it is help me, thanks.

Comment: @yantrab I strongly recommend you to once go through the documentation part before use.

Comment: if you just want allow admin to access path then you can put that condition in your canactivate method, right ? or that can be passed as depedancy then what is use of using extra package

Answer (score 0):

What we are following is, Implement Two Guards AuthGuard(To enable Authentication for APIs) and CleanGuard(To disable Authentication).

Now, Specify and configure AuthGuard and CleanGuard in `app-routing.module.ts`. It's more flexible for us to enable Authentication for specific set of APIs and some for not.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'pages', canActivate: [AuthGuard], loadChildren: 'app/pages/pages.module#PagesModule' },
  {
    path: 'auth',
    component: JGAuthComponent,
    canActivate: [CleanGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: LoginComponent,
      },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'pages', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'pages' },
];
```

CleanGuard

```
@Injectable()
export class CleanGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
    private tokenService: JGTokenService) {
  }

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    this.tokenService.clear();
    return observableOf(true);
  }
}
```

AuthGuard

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router) {
  }

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.authService.isAuthenticated()
      .pipe(
        tap(authenticated => {
          if (!authenticated) {
            this.router.navigate(['auth/login']);
          }
        }),
        catchError((d) => {
          this.router.navigate(['auth/login']);
          return observableOf(false);
        }),
      )
  }
}
```